# How to create an IAttachmentID using Trello.Net?

Tags: c#, api, attachment, trello, trello.net

I'm using dillenmeister's Trello.Net API wrapper, and I see that removing an attachment from a card was added a couple months ago, but the call that I'm using (`Trello.Cards.RemoveAttachment()`) calls for a `CardId` and an `IAttachmentId`. I've figured out how to create a `CardId` (`new CardID(Card.ID)`), but I'm not seeing how to create the `IAttachmentID` that it's looking for.

I have the attachment object, and can get the `ID` from there, but that is of type string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Attachment` class itself implements `IAttachmentId`.

```
// Example: Remove all attachments with the name "DevSupport" from a card 
var card = trello.Cards.WithId("a card id");
foreach (var attachment in card.Attachments.Where(a => a.Name == "DevSupport"))
    trello.Cards.RemoveAttachment(card, attachment);
```

It's similar for many other objects, for example the `Card` class implements `ICardId`. You do not need to create a `CardId` object if you have a `Card`. Just use the actual `Card`.

```
// Example: Fetch all members assigned to a card
var card = trello.Cards.WithId("a card id");
var members = trello.Members.ForCard(card);
```

There might be a need for an `AttachmentId` class anyway though. What is your use case?

Comment: When we move a `Card` to one `Board` in particular we are adding a cover image, and we want to remove only that image when the `Card` is returned to any other `Board`. When adding the `Attachment`' I'm giving it a `Name` as well, so here is the code that I was planning on using to remove: 
    foreach (Card.Attachment att in attch)
            {
                if (att.Name.ToString().Equals("DevSupport", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    t.Cards.RemoveAttachment(cID, att);
                }
            }

Where `cID` is a `CardID`.

Comment: I updated the first example to be more relevant to what I think you want to do.

Comment: Yes, the code looks great and works like I was hoping. Thanks.